# Mac OS: print PDF in landscape orientation from command line

Tags: macos, pdf, printing, terminal, landscape

I am trying to print a pdf in landscape orientation (90 degrees rotated) from the command line with this command:

```
lp -o landscape test.pdf
```

Besides the fact that it is minimized from A4 to A5 (which is correct) it is still printed in portrait modein the lower left corner of the paper.

This command has the same effect:

```
lp -o orienation-requested=4 test.pdf
```

When I try it from the preview app, it works, but I have to switch off "rotate automatically". Unfortunately there is no command line equivalent for the lp command (I know). Can anyone help?

P.S. When i try this with a text file everything works fine...

Comment: The command `lp -o orientation-requested=4 test.pdf` is working as expected for me... Could be a weird issue with your printer?

Comment: Is it working with .pdf file ? I am facing similar issue, landscape is working with .txt file but not with .pdf file.

Comment: Yes. In the meantime it works with all kind of files. See my comment below the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

heinob--

I believe this is the proper syntax to enter in the command line for what you're trying to do:

```
lp -o landscape -o fit-to-page -o media=A4 test.pdf
```

Then again, it could just be a weird issue with your printer.

Comment: The output is now centered in the middle of the page. Still A5 (which would be o.k. when turned) but also still portrait. Did you try it with a pdf yourself?

Comment: It has been a printer issue. After reinstalling the printer driver. Everything worked fine.